# SQL Query for Inactive Users

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table which tracks user activity in a game. Activity information is stored into category and sub-category fields. For every activity that the user performs, a record gets created in the this table. Now I want to find the users who are inactive for the last 30 days.

Table Columns

- ID
- Username
- Group_name
- Activity_Category
- Activity_Subcategory
- Activity_Date

Please let me know if more information is required.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: It is MYSQL database.

Comment: show us what you have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aggregation:

```
select user_name
from t
group by user_name
having max(activity_date) <= current_date - interval '30 day';
```

Note that date/time functions are highly database specific.  So this exact syntax may not work in your database, but the idea should work.

If you have a separate table of users, it is probably faster to use `not exists`:

```
select u.*
from users u
where not exists (select 1
                  from activity a
                  where a.username = u.username and
                        a.activity_date <= current_date - interval '30 day'
                 );
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but would this not give me all the users who are active in the last 30 days instead of the in-active users ?

Answer (score 0):

No activity within the last 30 days means the latest activity was over 30 days ago:

```
select user_name, max(activity_date)
from tab
group by username
having max(activity_date) < current_date - interval '30' day;
```